# Convert array to object with key

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

I have an object as

```
{
    ids: ['11', '12', '13', '14'],
    cat: 1
}
```

I want to convert this to

```
[
    { id: '11', cat: 1 },
    { id: '12', cat: 1 },
    { id: '13', cat: 1 },
    { id: '14', cat: 1 }
]
```

Is it possible to do this single syntax? Can we use spread syntax for this?

Comment: That is not JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's just a `map` over `ids`.

```js
var obj = {
  ids: ['11', '12', '13', '14'],
  cat: 1
};
console.log(obj.ids.map((x) => {
  return {
    id: x,
    cat: obj.cat
  };
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive function which separates all key/value pairs and build a new cartesian product by iterating the values, if an array with objects call `getCartesian` again and build new objects.

The keys must have the same name as later in the result set.

```js
function getCartesian(object) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var temp = [];
        r.forEach(s =>
            (Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]).forEach(w =>
                (w && typeof w === 'object' ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
                    temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [k]: x }))
                )
            )
        );
        return temp;
    }, [{}]);
}

var data = { id: ['11', '12', '13', '14'], cat: 1 };

console.log(getCartesian(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = {
  ids: ['11', '12', '13', '14'],
  cat: 1
}

// one line
test.ids.map(i => { return {id: i, cat: test.cat} } )
```